# In ReactJS, what steps are taken on server and what steps are taken on client when rendering a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and although I followed a couple of very good tutorials and I read the Getting Started part of the docs, I'm failing to understand a basic principle on how ReactJS actually works.

When serving a page, what really happens behind? Is the code in the `render` section called on server and the result returned? Does the client somehow merge the resulting "virtual" DOM with the browser's DOM? How is browser compatibility mitigated in this case.

I'm basically looking for the anatomy of a React page request. Are there any resources available that cover this part?

Comment: Reading the official documentation will help you much more than asking on SO.

Comment: @Striped I might be missing something, but the docs (I did the Quick Start section) are heavily focused on how to actually do things rather that explaining the inner workings. I'll have another look over them.

Comment: Did you look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html ? And there is an Advance Guide on the right menu.

Answer (score 1):

*The below is just my opinion. Please correct me if I need to correct something below*

In react if you are not talking about server side rendering, only the first request will go to server to get required files. All the required components will be brought to client side in form of javascript files(unless you have lazy loading of components)

So whenever you have a component rendered, react libraries(that are bundled from the initial request) will be taking care of rendering the component and any of the click events are also handled by react libraries.

Suppose you have a functionality where you are getting data from server. Say on button click you need to get list of employees and then display in a component, you make an ajax call from your component(unless you are using some other state management techniques) and just do a setState() with the result of your ajax call. setState() is one of the main react method which helps in updating state for a component. This state can also be sent to its children and make them render using the props that the child component received. 
Also comparision of actual DOM tree vs the virtual DOM is also done at client side itself very intelligently react and only required DOM node where there are changes will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

> When serving a page, what really happens behind?

If it is not server-side rendering, the usual flow is like this:

- You hit URL in the browser. Browser asks the server to return something.
- Server returns a `html` file. In react case, that `html` file should contain your `react` application's bundle inside `<script>` tags. Usually look something like

`<script src="www.yourdomain.com/bundle.js"></script>`

- Once browser receive this `html` it start executing this. And it will again ask the server to get that `react app bundle` file mentioned in the script tag.
- Since this `html` file does not contain anything to show on browser, it will wait for react app bundle.
- Once this `bundle` is received (which is just javascript), browser will start executing it. From here, your react app takes control of what needs to be rendered. So whatever react application return from `render` function, will be shown in browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to it honestly.

Here are the steps.

1. Server is responsible for serving a page with empty html element (usually div#app)
2. Server is also responsible for serving data to react app via API, again usually (always) in a form of JSON.
3. On the client (the browser) your JS script code written using react API is rendering all of your content (components) into the empty html element mentioned above and also utilized the fetched data.

Ofc there is a lot more to how React itself works (virtual DOM and such), but this is just a standard flow explained, hope you find it understandable.